# Mark a field as transient for one datasource but not another in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I've got an app that sends data to SQL Server, and we'd like to expand it to also write to another data source (possibly amazon s3, but possibly a regular database). The issue is, this new database only needs a subset of the fields in my entity class.

Is there a way that I can mark a field as being transient for one datasource but not another? Or should I be doing something on the Repository level? I'm using Spring Data JPA, and had been using a Spring-generated JpaRepository.

```
public interface JobRepository extends JpaRepository<MyPojo, Long>{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create two different repository interfaces for two different data sources. In this case, you will need to create two different entities-one for each data source and bind them in your services.

**For Data Source A: AEntity, ARepository
For Data Source B: BEntity, BRepository**

And in your services, you create a method:

**public AEntity createAEntityFromBEntity(BEntity bEntity);**

To be able to do this, you will need to mark one of your data sources as @Primary. Please check [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) link to see how to create two different data source connections with configuration details.